# How do write a java script function that returns a single value and assign the returned value to variable any where we want?

Tags: javascript, return, return-value

How do write a java script function that returns a single value and assign the returned value to variable any where we want ?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If not, try looking for some tutorials.

Comment: How about reading a JavaScript tutorial? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function which returns a value:

```
function getValue() {
    return 1;
}
```

Assign the value to a variable:

```
var value = getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

`let foo = (_ => 'bar')(); // trollolol`